# Bootstrap 5 Open Modal with YouTube Autoplay when Modal ID Entered as URL

Tags: youtube, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and some JS.

I have a button that launches a Bootstrap 5 Modal and autoplays a YouTube video. When the modal shows, the video plays and the URL is appended to include the modal ID. When the modal closes, it removes the modal ID from the URL and the video stops.

I want users to be able to enter the URL that includes the modal ID (i.e. domain.com/#announcement) and the modal to automatically open on page load and autoplay the YouTube video. I've got it to open the modal successfully, but it does not play the video. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

## Button HTML

```
<a href="#announcement" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-tagVideo="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ifumHS47fSw" data-bs-target="#announcement">Announcement</a>
```

## Bootstrap 5 Modal HTML

```
<div class="modal modal-video fade" data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static" id="announcement" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="announcement" aria-hidden="true">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close d-block d-sm-none" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="btn-close d-none d-sm-block" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="modal-body" disabled>
        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
          <iframe src="" allow="autoplay;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
// Modal YouTube Autoplay
function autoPlayYouTubeModal() {
  var triggerOpen = $("body").find('[data-tagVideo]');
  triggerOpen.click (function() {
    var theModal = $(this).data("bs-target"),
      videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-tagVideo"),
      videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?controls=1&autoplay=1";
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' button.btn-close').click(function() {
      $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  autoPlayYouTubeModal();
});

// Append Modal ID to URL On Modal Open and Remove on Close
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    if (typeof(e.relatedTarget) != "undefined") {
      window.location.hash = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');
    }
  });

  $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    var urlReplace = window.location.toString().split('#', 1)[0];
    history.replaceState(null, null, urlReplace);
  });
});

// Open Modal When User Types in Modal Link
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.modal').each(function () {
    const modalId = `#${$(this).attr('id')}`;
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(modalId) !== -1) {
      $(modalId).modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

I believe I need to duplicate part of the autoPlayYouTubeModal function in the last JS section when the modal shows.